# Smartsheet C Sharp SDK DLL error in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have completed my code and i am looking to compile and release the software.  I have worked my way through all of the bugs/error messages when i changed from debug to release except for 1 that has got my head hurting!

Looking for some help to solve this as dr google has not helped.

I have searched their SDK kit and there help text with no luck

Error CS1759

Cannot embed interop types from assembly 'smartsheet-csharp-sdk, Version=2.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is missing either the System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the System.Runtime.InteropServices.PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute' attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure that I totally understand what is going on here either, but, have you tried with later versions of the Smartsheet SDK? Version 2.2.1 is pretty old at this point.

Comment: i downloaded this version in November last year so not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago and there are two things you should do.

1. Update smartsheet-csharp-sdk NuGet package to latest version 2.6 (in
   my case). Keep in mind there are three dependencies that might need
   to be updated too.(NLog.Config, RestSharp & Newtonsoft.Json)
2. It seems you are combining the "Embed Interop Types" feature with
   use of a class type. There is a limitation with this type
   restricting embed feature. Update its value "Embed Interop Type" to false.

[Here is the screenshot if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVtak.png)